# Non-isolated DC/DC converter safety question

Tags: dc, surge-protection, circuit-breaker

If I were to have a 350VDC or similar bus voltage, protected by solid state switches meaning near instantaenous shut-down, what would the safety implications be if I were to use to step down this 350VDC to 48VDC or similar at the load side?

Should I used a surge protector rated for 48VDC (shorting in the case of overvoltage which would trigger the solid state to switch,) or should I use appropriate breakers at the output of the down converter?

I am not concerned on the transmission side of things, just the implications from the down converter brick onwards.

Comment: Safety as in human safety or that the connected device doesn’t get blown up??

Comment: Human safety, failure of the dc/dc converter with non isolation meaning 48vdc is now 350vdc

Comment: How will a surge protector (a standard device) trigger the solid-state switch? Better to use fuses and a crowbar circuit IMHO. Is the bus voltage safety earthed on one terminal?

Comment: The solid state switches/ protection circuit would have to be safety rated. What is the source of 350V? Mains or battery?

Comment: When the surge protector is activated, the sudden increase in current would shut down the solid state switch (80ma at 2.5ms would result in this). Trying to remove the need for a fuse (manual reset device) if possible

Comment: @Kartman it is, it is certified as touch safe. It comes from a single source which is galvanically isolated - e.g. a.c mains to 350vdc.

Comment: Breakers and surge protectors won't protect a human from shock. And you can't trust solid-state switches to protect since they fail short. What does touch-safe even mean? Is that double-insulated and safe to touch in the event of no electrical failure? Or safe even if the electronics short out? Difficult to see how that is possible if non-isolated.

Comment: @DKNguyen if you have a look into UL1401 you'll see a description for fault managed power systems, which are themselves typically advertised as touch safe - the system will shut-down before any harm can be done to yourself.